# Are we for, um, burning [forum]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forum) tag says:

> A forum, or message board, is an online discussion site where
> people can hold conversations in the form of posted messages.
> They differ from chat rooms in that messages are at least
> temporarily archived. Also, depending on the access level of a
> user or the forum set-up, a posted message might need to be
> approved by a moderator before it becomes visible.

What does this have to do with programming???

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

What does it mean? using a forum, programming a forum, ...?

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Does it matter if the code is being used in a forum? No.

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It's about a forum. We don't know anything else. Fail!

#### Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?

Questions about using forums are off-topic.

Questions like:

> I need a forum where users can make posts, how can I make one?
> [closed]

are closed as 'needs more focus'.

Can we burn it?

Comment: Are we for, um, burning [forum]?

Comment: @kjhughes : that would have been a great title

Comment: You make a lot of good points. I'm all for 'em.

Comment: Don't forget to put `[SOLVED]` into the title when the tag is burninated ;) /s

Comment: what about a forum software ? lie [tag:phpbb], [tag:invision-power-board], etc

Comment: @c69 you would create tags for them individually, no generic forum tag is needed.

Comment: sure... just pointing out that tag [tag:search] has 30K questions and seems to be ok,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search while all the same questions can be applied to that one as well..

Answer (score 62):

The only consistent trends I see among the first couple pages of questions tagged [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forum) are:

- Questions about various forum software packages.  These mostly have their own tags, and generally seem to already be tagged with those tags.  Nothing to do here.
- Questions about writing forum software.  Nothing to do here either.

I can't find any case where this tag adds any useful information whatsoever.  Other than a pass through the question list to find close-worthy questions and close them (a lot of the questions under the second bullet point above are vague and/or opinion-based), I'd say this tag could simply be removed in its entirety with no loss of useful information.

Comment: *I can't find any case where this tag adds any useful information whatsoever. Other than a pass through the question list to find close-worthy questions and close them*: That, exactly that...